# The indexPath of a specific UITableViewCell is always nil

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionview, xcode8, indexpath

After the update to Xcode8 the following code doesn't work anymore

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    let cell = collectionView.superview!.superview as! UITableViewCell
    let table = cell.superview!.superview as! UITableView
    let indexPath = table.indexPath(for: cell)
```

Now the value of indexPath is always nil.
Any ideas?

Comment: Examine the hierarchy in the debugger, starting with the collectionView, running up the superview list.  After you figure it out, post the answer here.

Comment: I've checked the hierarchy and the superview list. Everything seems to be okay. I can see in the debugger that there is a value for indexPath but after the line "let indexPath = table.indexPath(for: cell)" the value changes to nil.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by replacing the last line with

```
let indexPath = table.indexPathForRow(at: cell.center)
```

Comment: Can anyone explain, why this way is working and the other one not?